# merge columns of line n+1 to line n

Tags: linux, shell, awk, scripting

iostat can show persistent device names (with -j id) instead of kernel device names (e.g. sda) but this also implies the option -h for "human readable" output.
This results in output like this (a line that contains the persistent disk name, e.g. HOMES or DATADISK and the next line contains the values for that disk).

(in my example I piped the output of iostat to awk '// {print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),$0}' to have a timestamp at the beginning of every line):

```
2018-06-13 11:57:03 HOMES
2018-06-13 11:57:03                   0.00     0.00    0.00    0.50     0.00     2.00     8.00     0.00    1.00    0.00    1.00   1.00   0.05
2018-06-13 11:57:03 ARCHIVEDISK
2018-06-13 11:57:03                   0.00     0.00    0.00    0.50     0.00     2.00     8.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
2018-06-13 11:57:03 DATADISK
2018-06-13 11:57:03                   0.00     0.00   86.00    0.50   680.00     2.00    15.77     0.12    1.40    1.41    1.00   1.26  10.90
2018-06-13 11:57:05 HOMES
2018-06-13 11:57:05                   0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
2018-06-13 11:57:05 ARCHIVEDISK
2018-06-13 11:57:05                   0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
2018-06-13 11:57:05 DATADISK
2018-06-13 11:57:05                   0.00     0.00  122.00  116.00   976.00  1164.00    17.98     0.56    2.33    3.36    1.26   1.47  34.90
```

how can I merge the lines so I get this:

```
2018-06-13 11:57:03 HOMES             0.00     0.00    0.00    0.50     0.00     2.00     8.00     0.00    1.00    0.00    1.00   1.00   0.05
2018-06-13 11:57:03 ARCHIVEDISK       0.00     0.00    0.00    0.50     0.00     2.00     8.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
2018-06-13 11:57:03 DATADISK          0.00     0.00   86.00    0.50   680.00     2.00    15.77     0.12    1.40    1.41    1.00   1.26  10.90
2018-06-13 11:57:05 HOMES             0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
2018-06-13 11:57:05 ARCHIVEDISK       0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
2018-06-13 11:57:05 DATADISK          0.00     0.00  122.00  116.00   976.00  1164.00    17.98     0.56    2.33    3.36    1.26   1.47  34.90
```

Comment: Wouldn't the better approach be to fix the awk command that's producing this output rather than creating a new awk command to process the existing awk commands output? Right now it's like you're asking how to bandage your foot after shooting it - just don't shoot it...

Comment: most of the output ist done by iostat. awk just adds the date/time at beginning of line.
sure, I possibly could implement e.g. olivs solution to the first awk... but I prefer 2 "simple" awk commands instead of 1 "more complex" one...

Comment: Since you don't know what the one awk command is, you don't know if it's more complex than 2 awk commands joined by a pipe or not. I'd expect it to be less complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk 'NF==3{n=$3;next}{for(i=NF;i>2;i--) $(i+1)=$i;$3=n}1' file | column -t
```

The `awk` script gets the name if the line contains 3 elements. 
For all other lines, it shifts all elements by one position except for the first 2. 
At last the line is printed.

The command `column` is reformatting to display it per column.

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -pe 'if ($. % 2) {
    chomp;
    $l = length;
} else {
    s/^.{19} */" " x (38 - $l)/e;
}' -- file
```

- `$.` contains the input line number
- `%` is the modulo operator, i.e. `$. % 2` returns true for lines 1, 3, 5, 7, etc.
- `/e` interprets the replacement part of `s///` substitution as code, here it repeats a space `38 - $l` times, where `$l` is the length of the previous line (to align the numbers)

Answer (score 1):

awk, maintains the spacing:

```
awk '
    NR % 2 {label = $3; next}
    {print substr($0, 1, 19), label, substr($0, 22 + length(label))}
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If the iostat output looks like this:

```
$ cat file
HOMES
                  0.00     0.00    0.00    0.50     0.00     2.00     8.00     0.00    1.00    0.00    1.00   1.00   0.05
ARCHIVEDISK
                  0.00     0.00    0.00    0.50     0.00     2.00     8.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
DATADISK
                  0.00     0.00   86.00    0.50   680.00     2.00    15.77     0.12    1.40    1.41    1.00   1.26  10.90
HOMES
                  0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
ARCHIVEDISK
                  0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
DATADISK
                  0.00     0.00  122.00  116.00   976.00  1164.00    17.98     0.56    2.33    3.36    1.26   1.47  34.90
```

then all you need is 1 small, simple awk command (using `cat file` in place of `iostat` below):

```
$ cat file | awk 'NR%2{dev=$0; next} {printf "%s %-18s %s\n", strftime("%F %T"), dev, substr($0,19)}'
2018-06-22 10:34:09 HOMES              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.50     0.00     2.00     8.00     0.00    1.00    0.00    1.00   1.00   0.05
2018-06-22 10:34:09 ARCHIVEDISK        0.00     0.00    0.00    0.50     0.00     2.00     8.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
2018-06-22 10:34:09 DATADISK           0.00     0.00   86.00    0.50   680.00     2.00    15.77     0.12    1.40    1.41    1.00   1.26  10.90
2018-06-22 10:34:09 HOMES              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
2018-06-22 10:34:09 ARCHIVEDISK        0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
2018-06-22 10:34:09 DATADISK           0.00     0.00  122.00  116.00   976.00  1164.00    17.98     0.56    2.33    3.36    1.26   1.47  34.90
```

No need to be adding timestamps then removing them again, calling strftime unnecessarily, looping through fields, pipes, calls to "column" that will mess up your original alignment, etc.